# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to execute a .jar file which I produced from a JavaFX project (i already set the VM Options in Intellij with module path and modules to include) but I keep getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
> at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> at main.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:5)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> ... 10 more

I also have a Launcher class, which Main method just does `Main.main(args)`, where Main is the class that extends Application.
What can i do more?
This is the main class of my project

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/InserimentoPorta.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("EP Miner");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

And there are 3 controllers, one for each of my fxml file (i'm not posting the controllers code because the question would be too long and i don't think it's necessary to solve this problem)

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code? There is no way of telling what is wrong, from a compiler error to a typo in the class name everything is possible as far as i can tell from this question.

Comment: “i already set the VM Options in Intellij with module path and modules to include” ->To what? Which instructions and methods did you follow from openjfx.io (name the section)?  Are you using a third party build tool?  Which one?  Did you define module-Info? Did you install a JavaFX SDK?  Are you using that or Maven central modules?  What is your environment OS, JDK, JavaFX versions? (Edit the question to provide the answers, comments not necessary). If using modules from Maven, use JavaFX 16 for now as 17 currently has issued with Maven central packaging.